# Update PHP cURL request from SSLv3 to TLS..?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

Because of the [recent vulnerability discovered in SSLv3](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123), many web service providers (ie. PayPal, Facebook, Google) are disabling that and wanting us to use TLS instead.  I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to do this.

I'm currently using the following function to handle my cURL requests.

```
function CURLRequest($Request = "", $APIName = "", $APIOperation = "", $PrintHeaders = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->EndPointURL);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Request);

    if($this->APIMode == 'Certificate')
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->PathToCertKeyPEM);
    }

    $Response = curl_exec($curl);

    /*
     * If a cURL error occurs, output it for review.
     */
    if($this->Sandbox)
    {
        if(curl_error($curl))
        {
            echo curl_error($curl).'<br /><br />';  
        }
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    return $Response;   
}
```

When I try hitting PayPal's sandbox, though, where they've already disabled this, I end up with a cURL error:  *error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure*

The info that I've found is that I just need to change this to use TLS instead of SSL, and the other answers I've seen say to simply do that by adding a curl option to my function...

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

I've added that option, though, and I still get the exact same result.  Any information on how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you on an old version of Curl? Looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452755/php-curl-is-probably-using-sslv3-insted-of-tls-when-connecting-to-https) it seems at least 7.19 has issues with TLS.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that, too.  Trying to figure out how to see my curl version now.  I've never had to mess with any of this before.

Comment: Looks like I'm on 7.36.0, so that shouldn't be my problem.

Comment: might be a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759383/ssl-error-can-not-change-to-tls eventhough this one is better formulated.

Comment: Indeed!  That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copied from: [SSL error can not change to TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759383/ssl-error-can-not-change-to-tls)

Try add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');` to your code.

This will work if you cURL is OpenSSL **libssl** based but not if **nss** based.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done the trick.  Should we merge these somehow..??

Comment: i prefer your wording that are more general than duplicate answer, but to let to caesar what is to caesar this answer is not mine...

Comment: @philippelhardy, I am getting the sslv3 handshake failure even though i've  `CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST` set to TLSv1

Answer (score 4):

A better solution until Paypal updates its core SDK would be to override the CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST directly in your application. This way you don't have to interfere with the sdk-core-php package directly and you will be free to upgrade it in future.

You could add something like the following to your app's bootstrap or payment processing logic:

```
PPHttpConfig::$DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST] = 'TLSv1';
```

Just make sure you comment it thoroughly and remember to take it out later when the issue has been patched in the core.

Comment: Can you please go into detail where (path/file or settings) I have to add this line. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Raffael, you could add it anywhere you are certain will get called on every pageload. This depends on your framework but usually it will have some kind of "bootstrap"/configuration  file where you can add this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved updating `nss` library via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not help, check OPENSSL version. Its likely because of OPENSSL version <= 0.9.8. Updating to PHP7 helps, which comes with higher version of OPENSSL.