# Php - cUrl support TLSv1 connection

Tags: php, ssl, curl

My payment gataway will change the connection protocol using TLS 1.0 or higher.

I have php 5.5 with library CUrl 7.19.7 (NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC), that supports only CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (according with this link http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/symbols-in-versions.html).

Should be fine too?. What is the difference between set CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0.

Thank you very much, for your time

Comment: have you tried searching the difference on internet?

Comment: Yes but i haven't found nothing

Answer (score 1):

- TLSv1: use TLS 1.x, i.e. TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2. These might not be all available depending on the underlying implementation.
- TLSv1_0: use only TLS 1.0, i.e. no TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 even if the implementation would support this.

If your implementation supports at most TLS 1.0 then both options should have the same effect.

BTW, the very first hit with google when searching for "CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1" is http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html which documents these options as:

- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1: TLS 1.x
- CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0: TLS 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the help. Some people noted that the cUrl 7.19.7 version has bugs with CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1, probably i will have many problems.

Comment: "...some people noted..." - could you be more specific? There is a nice feature of the web called "links" which you could use to point to other information and there is "text" to describe issues. And finally there is "space" to leave all the useful information away. Please make more use of the first two features.

Comment: Calm down : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452755/php-curl-with-nss-is-probably-using-sslv3-insted-of-tls-when-connecting-to-htt/26453701#26453701  Is it you?

Comment: This is not a problem with TLSv1 but a problem with a server only supporting ciphers which the client does not support. I think you should better try to understand what you read. And yes, it's me.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the brutal help